# table are not fitting in a section

Tags: html, css

I made a table, with two table-cell in it. I place this table in a section. But it's not fitting inside, see the image bellow[image: when I put a background color at my section in red, here is what appears]

How to make it fit inside the section ?
Here is my code

```css
#theme{background-color:red}
.acent{
 padding-left: 14%; padding-right: 14%; 
 }
.startstart {  
   display: table;
   width: 100%; 
   float: left; 
   background-color:green;}

  .startgauche {
   display: table-cell; 
   width: 33.33%; 
   height:100%;
   display: inline-block; 
   float: left; 
  }

  .startdroite {display: table-cell; 
    margin-top: 25px;
  width: 66.66%; 
  height:100%;
  display: inline-block; 
  float: left; }
```

```html
<section id="theme">

  <h2>My title</h2>

 <div class="acent">
  <div class="startstart">


      <div class="startgauche">
     blabla
     </div>


     <div class="startdroite">     
     blabla 2
    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `display: flex`. Below is an updated solution

```css
#theme {
  background-color: red
}
.acent {
  padding-left: 14%;
  padding-right: 14%;
  display: flex;
}
.startstart {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}
.startgauche {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.startdroite {
  display: table-cell;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 66.66%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="theme">

  <h2>My title</h2>

  <div class="acent">
    <div class="startstart">
      <div class="startgauche">
        blabla
      </div>
      <div class="startdroite">
        blabla 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If you using display table property don't use floating property. its create problems.

please check working fiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b4mhL0q0/

Answer (score 0):

Google `clearfix`.

The simpliest solution is

```
#theme { 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
#theme{background-color:red; overflow: hidden;}
.acent{
 padding-left: 14%; padding-right: 14%; 
 }
.startstart {  
   display: table;
   width: 100%; 
   float: left; 
   background-color:green;}

  .startgauche {
   display: table-cell; 
   width: 33.33%; 
   height:100%;
   display: inline-block; 
   float: left; 
  }

  .startdroite {display: table-cell; 
    margin-top: 25px;
  width: 66.66%; 
  height:100%;
  display: inline-block; 
  float: left; }
```

```html
<section id="theme">

  <h2>My title</h2>

 <div class="acent">
  <div class="startstart">


      <div class="startgauche">
     blabla
     </div>


     <div class="startdroite">     
     blabla 2
    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `float:left` in main div which is creating problem you need to clear that float with following html

**HTML**

```
<section id="theme">

  <h2>My title</h2>

  <div class="acent">
    <div class="startstart">


      <div class="startgauche">
        blabla
      </div>


      <div class="startdroite">
        blabla 2
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clear">

      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.clear{
  clear:both
}
#theme {
  background-color: red
}

.acent {
  padding-left: 14%;
  padding-right: 14%;
}

.startstart {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

.startgauche {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.startdroite {
  display: table-cell;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 66.66%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/eb398g1y/